# JSON and JavaScript error

Tags: javascript, json

please help me with these errors.
I have written a restful api to store the data in java and used a json object to get the details and just send a success response. but I don't know what error is this.

[image]

Comment: console log detailsJSON and look at what you are passing through

Comment: The response you're getting is not JSON because of the 404 error. Probably a typo. "sumit" instead of "submit"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Post your code as plain text, not an image. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting for code formatting help.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use an object as the argument to `xhttp.send()`, it needs to be either a string or `FormData`. To send JSON, you have to call `JSON.stringify()`, it doesn't happen automatically by passing an object:

```
xhttp.send(JSON.stringify(detailsJson));
```

You're also getting a 404 error because you have a typo in the URL you're submitting to.